# Convergence of Lesbegue measure of the images of a sequences converging uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, hausdorff-measure

Good morning, my answer is related to the one introduced here

[Convergence of images of a sequence of converging continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142753/convergence-of-images-of-a-sequence-of-converging-continuous-functions/4878876#4878876)

but with stronger hypotheses. Suppose you have a sequence of invertible functions $f_n$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on a limited domain $X$. Moreover $f_n$ and $f$ are Lipschitz and the L. constants $L_n$ of $f_n$ converges to the one of $f$.

If $A$ is an open set, can we prove that

$$
|f_n(A) \setminus f(A)| \to 0 ?
$$

Do you know any references?